# Checking for existing HttpSession in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible to authenticate a user by checking for an existing HttpSession within Spring Security?  I would like users to authenticate via CAS at one URL (http://example.com/auth), but not the other URLs.  For example, if they go straight to http://example.com/content, then I'd like to check for the HttpSession and return a 401 Unauthorized code if they haven't logged into CAS yet.  If they've already gone to the /auth page and logged in, then going to /content will return the content.  The main reason for this is to avoid any redirects that CAS causes during authentication.

I am kind of new to Spring Security and can't figure out if I need a custom AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationEntryPoint, both, or something else.  The AuthenticationManager doesn't have a way for me to access the HttpSession, and the AuthenticationEntryPoint doesn't seem to be the right place to implement this functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security is not using HTTP session. 
Instead, you can easily call to this static method:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Frankly, I believe that you need to configure Spring security correct in order to avoid checking authentication and redirect manually to other page.

Comment: Yes, I normally would configuration Spring Security 'correctly', but I have a situation where I need to prevent CAS redirects on certain pages when the session doesn't exist.

Comment: Where would I check the getAuthentication() method?  Would I use some kind of filter in Spring Security?